# Display an element for a week using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JS code is currently as follows:

```
var today = new Date(),
d = today.getDate(),
m = today.getMonth() + 1,
y = today.getFullYear(),
date = d + '/' + m + '/' + y,
specialDate = '22/10/2012';

if (date == specialDate) {
document.getElementById("doodle").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("defaultheader").style.display = "none";
} 
else {
document.getElementById("doodle").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("defaultheader").style.display = "block";
}
```

The code works perfectly but I'd now like to display `#doodle` for a week (22nd - 28th October) instead of one day. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be better to use `Date.now()` or `new Date().getTime()` to do this. Then you can compare two 'times':

```
var dateFrom = new Date('Oct 22 2012').getTime(),
    dateTo = new Date('Oct 28 2012').getTime();

var dateNow = new Date().getTime();

if (dateNow >= dateFrom && dateNow =< dateTo) {
    // show the element
} else {
    // hide it
}
```

## EDIT:

You also can create `dateFrom` and `dateTo` in your console and put numeric values there - if you need to optimize it.

Comment: Yeah, but for what do we need to store whole `Date` object in memory? Such a waste.